# How to access curl post data in a rest api in codeigniter?

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, curl, codeigniter-3

I want to post data from the Codeigniter controller using curl to API.
I'm not able to access the post data in API.
Here's my CURL code.
...

```
     class SearchJobs extends CI_Controller {


public function index()
{   
    $headers = array(

        'Content-Type:application/json'

    );

    $fields=$this->input->post();
    /////////////////////get jobs/////////////////

    $api_path=API_PATH."index.php/searchJobs/getJobs";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $featuredJobs = curl_exec($ch);


      if(curl_errno($ch)) {    
          echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);  

          exit();  
      } else {    
          // check the HTTP status code of the request
            $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if ($resultStatus != 200) {
                echo stripslashes($featuredJobs);
                die('Request failed: HTTP status code: ' . $resultStatus);

            }
         $featured_jobs_array=(array)json_decode($featuredJobs);
         print_r($featured_jobs_array);
         exit();
      } 


    $this->load->view('searchjobs/index',array('featuredJobs'=>$featured_jobs_array));
}
```

}

...

and this is how I'm accessing it in the API:

...

```
 public function getJobs_post()
{   
    $data_array=array();
    $res_array=array();
    $pageNo = $this->input->get('pageNo');

    $where = ' j.isActive="y" and isApproved=1  ';

    $posted_skills=$this->input->get('skills');

    $locations=$this->input->get('location');
```

...

But, I can easily access the post data in API from postman using the same method `$this->input->get('skills');`.

Comment: You are sending a _POST_ request, but you are using `$this->input->get` …?

Comment: @CBroe Yes i was using get because i was testing data through postman with query params. Then i changed that to form-data in body. Then it worked with $this->input->post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove Json Header**
 $headers = array(
         'Content-Type:application/json'
 );

and
**post data directly without json_encode**
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);